# Power BI DATEADD function returns blank for future dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, dateadd

In Power BI, I have a simple calendar created with the formula `CALENDAR = CALENDAR( DATE(2014,12,1),  TODAY())`.

 I added another column, that would contain dates 1 month later then the original Date column, with the formula `ADVANCED_DATES = DATEADD('CALENDAR'[Date], 1, MONTH)`.

I noticed that dates going into the future are left blank (today is 01/December/2023). Do you know what is causing it and how can I fix it?

(I have dates in the original Date column I am using, as you can see on the screenshot)

[image: Date table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATEADD(...)` is a Time Intelligence function, and as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dateadd-function-dax#remarks):

> The result table includes only dates that exist in the dates column.

So you will need to extend your `CALENDAR` to have the future dates needed.

Alternatively, if this is only for a Calculated Column then you can use this expression:

```
Date +1 Month = EDATE([Date], 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Tested it and this was the right solution for my problem!